# Sintaxe OR do Blade dentro do value do input do Laravel Collective

Tags: laravel, input, laravel-5.4

O seguinte `input` funciona normalmente, mas, quando eu passo ele para a sintaxe do *Laravel Collective*, diz que a variável `$servico` não existe. Ela não existe mesmo, então deveria mostrar o valor `null`).

A sintaxe do `OR` no `Collective` está errada?

INPUT NORMAL

```
<input type="text" name="nome" value="{{ $servico->cliente->nome or null }}" id="cliente" class="form-control" placeholder="Nome do cliente">
```

INPUT COLLECTIVE

```
{!! Form::input('text', 'nome', $servico->cliente->nome or null, ['id' => 'cliente', 'class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Nome do cliente']) !!}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No Collective, você terá que fazer com a sintaxe do PHP, já que essa sintaxe do `OR` do Blade é compila para uma expressão ternária com `isset`.

Para você entender melhor, quando você faz o "echo" do Blade assim

```
{{ $servico->cliente->nome or null }}
```

O Blade compila para

```
<?php echo isset($servico->cliente->nome) ? $servico->cliente->nome : null; ?>
```

Porém a sintaxe acima é reconhecida apenas com o uso direto da tag `{{ expressão }}`

No seu caso, você poderá usar uma expressão ternária diretamente, verificando se `$servico->cliente` existe para imprimir a propriedade `nome`;Caso contrário, você imprime o `null`

Exemplo:

```
{!! Form::input('text', 'nome', $servico->cliente ? $servico->cliente->nome : null, ['id'   => 'cliente', 'class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Nome do cliente']) !!}
```

Se você estiver usando as versões do PHP 7 ou superior, você poderá simplificar para

```
$servico->cliente->nome ?? null
```